# Save results as in 'corrupted file or invalid extension'

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro to generate a report. Everything is working fine. Macro finishes without any error messages. When I want to open the generated report, it comes up with the (t) error message:

> "Excel cannot open the file 'abc.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid."

When I save as a ***.xlsM*** it does work, but I don't want the macro to be available in the final report (to prevent people running it and avoid data-corruption).

This is the code I am using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & reportname & ".xlsx",
    fileFormat:=xlNormal
```

Any ideas are more then welcome!

Comment: Safe it as `.xls` or use the correct format (`FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`). The `FileFormat:=xlNormal` is not valid for Excel 2007++

Comment: @eckes, make that an answer instead of just a comment. Although, Chris, you'll want to use `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` since you don't want macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you indicated you do *not* want the final workbook to be macro enabled, this is what you want:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & reportname & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FileFormat:=xlNormal` is no longer recognized by Excel 2007 and newer. It safes the file therefore in traditional format, so your have to name it `.xls`.

According to the Online Help the new Format is called `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`(`MacroEnabled`).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Path As String
Dim ReportName As String

Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\"
ReportName = "abc.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    Path & ReportName, FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if the same name already exist at path then it will overwrite, no Alerts will be displayed and no macros will be saved